# Need to split a string after a certain length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to split a string into word "buckets" where each buckets has n or less characters.

Only include full words inside each bucket.

Here is the example:

```
bucketize("she sells sea shells by the sea", 10) // ➞ ["she sells", "sea shells", "by the sea"]
```

I have this code for the moment

```
function bucketize(string, number) {
    arrayOfWords = string.split(' ')
    const wordLengths = []
    arrayOfWords.forEach(word => wordLengths.push(word.length))
    maxLength = Math.max(...numArray)

}
```

but I don't see any way to achieve it, if anyone could help me :) thank you

Comment: Split the sentence, then add one word after another as long as the resulting string's length is `<= number`. Rinse and repeat...

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do that (not considering spaces as characters):

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(bucketize("she sells sea shells by the sea", 10)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(bucketize("she sells sea shells by the sea", 12)));

function bucketize(str, max) {
  let splitStr = str.split(/\s/);
  let tmp = "";
  let buckets = [];
  while (splitStr.length) {
    tmp += ` ${splitStr.shift()}`;
    if (tmp.length + tmp.match(/\s/g).length > max) {
      buckets.push(tmp.trim());
      tmp = "";
    }
  }
  tmp.length && buckets.push(tmp.trim());
  return buckets;
}
```